# What powers did Gol D. Roger possess?

Tags: one-piece

I am a big fan of the **One Piece** manga. I just started watching the anime (completed 3 seasons).

I was wondering: What powers did the Pirate King Gol D. Roger possess?

Is there any chapter/episode which reveals his powers? Or is there any theory about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has not been any information about the Gol D Roger power. Though there are some episode where part of Gol D. Roger are connected but information about him is very low. Main information about him are about family member, some crew, cause of death, very few information about his treasure One Piece but information of power has not been revealed. There are some more information about him in this [wiki page](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Gol_D._Roger).

As the story is progressing lots of thing are untold or unknown which may be revealed in future.

Comment: I would really appreciate if the down voter would leave the comment(reason) for voting down

Answer (score 1):

There is a theory which says that Gol D. Roger ate an Akuma no Mi, which made him capable of speaking/understanding any language. It would explain why he could understand the Poneglyphs, and why he was the most wanted man (before Dragon), because in terms of strength/power, he was Whitebeard's rival. However, this is just a theory (I think).

Comment: `Some say Gol D. Roger ate an Akuma no Mi` Is this said in One Piece manga, or is it just some fan theory?

Comment: I don't read the manga, I just watch the anime therefore I can't really tell. Maybe it's just a fan theory

Comment: I edited it to suggest that it's some existing fan theory, but if it is actually a theory made by characters in One Piece universe, feel free to edit it with citation.

Comment: In the manga it is said that he was able to hear the voice of all things - but it is **not** mentioned that he ate a devil fruit: [picture](http://i.imgur.com/cPVuu6t.png)

Comment: luffy and the siren princess could hear other voices.
I don't think this has to be related to a devil fruit or luffy would have eaten 2

Answer (score 0):

it is very plausible he is have a Weather Controlling Fruit.
In battle with Shiki the Golden Lion, Roger can win because of the storm destroyed majority of Shiki fleet.
and we know Weather controlling fruit exist when Monkey D.Dragon saving Luffy from execution in Logue Town.
so its a high possibilty Dragon found Roger DF after he died, hence He (Dragon) is named as the World Government's greatest enemy, and is the most dangerous and most wanted man in the world because World Government knows Roger`s power (probably from Garp) and what it can do.